# Error when trying to run java. "this selection cannot be launched" I tried everything listed here still doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm in a java class and have not gotten a response back from the instructor. I hope I can find help here.

Thank your for the help.

Instructions:
Design a class named a Rectangle to represent a rectangle The class contains:

a. Two double data fields named width and height that specify the width and height of the rectangle. The default values are 1 for both width and height

b. A no-argument constructor that creates a default rectangle

c. A constructor that creates a rectangle with specified width and height

d. Method named getArea() that returns the area of this rectangle

e. A method named getPerimeter() that returns the perimeter

f. Draw the UML diagram for the class and then implement the class.

g. Write a test program that create two rectangles objects one with a width 4 and height 40 and the other with width 3.5 and height 35.9.

h. Display the width height, area and the perimeter of each rectangle in this order on the console.

my code:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private double height;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle() {
        height = 1;
        width = 1;
    }

    public Rectangle(double hgt, double wdth) {
        height = hgt;
        width = wdth;
    }

    public void setHeight(double hgt) {
        height = hgt;
    }

    public void setWidth(double wdth) {
        width = wdth;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return height * width;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (height + width);
    }
}

class RectangleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(4.0, 40.0);
        Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(3.5, 35.9);
        System.out.println("Rectangle-1");
        // Display the area.
        System.out.println("The box's area is " + box1.getArea());
        // Display the perimeter.
        System.out.println("The box's perimeter is " + box1.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("Rectangle-2");
        // Display the area.
        System.out.println("The box's area is " + box2.getArea());
        // Display the perimeter.
        System.out.println("The box's perimeter is " + box2.getPerimeter());
    }
}
```

Here is what finally worked:

```
public double getPerimeter() {
    return 2 * (height + width);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(40.0, 4.0);
    Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(35.9, 3.5);
    System.out.println("Rectangle 1");
    System.out.println("width " + rectangle1.getWidth());
    System.out.println("height " + rectangle1.getHeight());
    System.out.println();

    // Display the area.
    System.out.println("The area of rectangle 1 " + rectangle1.getArea());

    // Display the perimeter.
    System.out.println("The box's perimeter is " + rectangle1.getPerimeter());
    System.out.println();


    System.out.println("Rectangle 2");
    System.out.println("width " + rectangle2.getWidth());
    System.out.println("height " + rectangle2.getHeight());
    System.out.println();

    // Display the area.
    System.out.println("The box's area is " + rectangle2.getArea());
    // Display the perimeter.
    System.out.println("The box's perimeter is " + rectangle2.getPerimeter());
}
```

}

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting and on what line? You need to be more clear about what is wrong with the code you have now.

Comment: Do you try to run `RectangleTest.main` or something else?

Comment: I have what you see above and it is showing no errors. When I try to run it in Eclipse I get the message "This selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

Comment: I removed RectangleTest and here is what have that worked.